# How does one constrain a Generic to an Enum AND a Integral numeric types

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

From the below URL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#enum-constraints

It reads

> Enum constraints Beginning in C# 7.3, you can also specify the
>   System.Enum type as a base class constraint. The CLR always allowed
>   this constraint, but the C# language disallowed it. Generics using
>   System.Enum provide type-safe programming to cache results from using
>   the static methods in System.Enum. The following sample finds all the
>   valid values for an enum type, and then builds a dictionary that maps
>   those values to its string representation.

with the example:

```
    public static Dictionary<int, string> EnumNamedValues<T>() where T : System.Enum
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));

        foreach (int item in values)
            result.Add(item, Enum.GetName(typeof(T), item));
        return result;
    }
```

Is there any way to constrain it to a Enum, but also with Integral numeric types ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types

example

```
    public static Dictionary<int, string> EnumNamedValues<T>() where T : System.Enum (uint)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));

        foreach (int item in values)
            result.Add(item, Enum.GetName(typeof(T), item));
        return result;
    }
```

The above syntax "System.Enum (uint)" does not work (or I wouldn't be asking the question of course! ).......but shows the intention of what I am asking.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to constrain the enum have a specific backing type, like `enum Foo : uint`? I don't believe this is possible to do with generics. I think the best you can do is constrain your type parameter to an `enum` and check it's backing type at runtime and throw a runtime exception if it is not an `uint`.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?:

```
    public enum Numbers
    {
            One = 1
            , Two
            , Three
            }

    ...
    ...
            public static Dictionary<int, string> EnumNamedValues<T>()
                    where T : unmanaged
            {
                    var result = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                    var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));

                    foreach (int item in values)
                            result.Add(item, Enum.GetName(typeof(T), item));
                    return result;
            }
    ...
    ...


    //valid:
    var dictInt = EnumNamedValues<int>();
    var dictByte = EnumNamedValues<System.SByte>();
    var dictEnum = EnumNamedValues<Numbers>();
    //not valid
    var dictString = EnumNamedValues<string>();
```

Comment: This won't work for any `enum` type with an `Int64` or `UInt64` backing-type. I note that this code only compiles because the `foreach` is performing a hidden cast, so it will blow-up at runtime.

Comment: The method `EnumNamedValues()` has been included in docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#enum-constraints